# Optimise SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to optimise this query ?

```
SELECT 
    tr.transferfrom, tr.transferto, br.id as 'BR_ID',tr.refno, 
    br.name as 'BR_NAME', br.code as 'BRANCH_CODE', tr.docno, tr.transdate,
    stk.stockno,stk.salescat,tr.qty, tr.sprice,tr.qty*tr.sprice as 'GROSS_SALES' 
FROM 
    TRANSFER tr 
JOIN 
    branch br on tr.branchid = br.id 
JOIN 
    stocks stk on tr.stockid=stk.id 
WHERE 
    RIGHT(tr.refno,7) = 'ST00576' AND LEFT(tr.refno,2) = 89 
    AND stk.stockno = 'NS4370 CR - L';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create index for `tr.refno` and replace `LEFT(tr.refno,2) = 89` with `tr.refno LIKE '89%'`
2. Create composite index `stk.id + stk.stockno`
3. Make sure `br.id` is covered by index
4. If there are really a lot of records (hundreds of millions) and this query if performed often - may be it makes sense to store last 7 `tr.refno` chars in separate field to avoid `RIGHT(tr.refno,7) = 'ST00576'` (not sure if sql server supports reverse indexes)

Comment: Point 4 makes no sense - set up an index on RIGHT(tr.refno,7) instead.

Comment: How would you do that, exactly?

Comment: @TomTom: and how single function-based index would help? If we had separated column - we could create `right_part_column + refno` composite index.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I have very limited knowledge on indexing the SQL server..

Comment: @redcoder: and what exactly is not clear?

Comment: is it some kind of setting in table property?

Comment: @redcoder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx